# Is it true that Bach had no concept of suspended chord?

Tags: chords, harmony, history, j-s-bach

In an answer to a question in SE I read the sentence with the pretension above.

[Chord in the Bach d-minor prelude](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32189/chord-in-the-bach-d-minor-prelude/32193#32193)

I think this can be easily be counter-proofed by  many examples of Bach’s music and especially in his figured bass.

Comment: Perhaps a link to the answer so we can see this claim in context would be useful?

Comment: These question/answer/comments are kind of a mess. Maybe this question should be deleted and the proper attention should be given to the original question https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32189/. Add better answers, and down vote the bad answer on the original question.

Comment: @Michael: thank you for your attention, Michael. I‘ve also tried to give  an answer over there and tried to explain where this misconcept could have come from. Now I wonder how it comes that I loose reputation points when I demonstrate that there is an accepted answer in a discussion of concepts and misconceptions which are probably opinion based ...

Comment: You certainly should not get a down vote. (I just up voted your answer and left comments.) Apparently some people can be petty. Hopefully others will revisit that post.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the first page that Google found when searching for 'Bach chorale'.  See the suspension?
Bach certainly wrote suspensions.  I wonder what the SE meant?

OK, now you've added the link.   He's discussing not whether Bach wrote suspensions, but whether Bach thought of them as such, as modifications of triad-based harmony.  A fair point.   It's good to remember that harmonies can arise from the combination of contrapuntal lines.   Guitarists in particular can fall into the trap of looking at chords as entities, ignoring the voice-leading element.

We can't look inside Bach's head, but my opinion is that Bach was quite aware of the patterns in homophonic harmonies, as well as being a master of counterpoint.  I think I disagree with the answer you quoted.  But the opinion stated isn't idiotic.

[image]

Comment: The answer has been accepted and has 10 upvotes ...

Comment: So you think I misunderstood the answer?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the point he was making, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is not true.

The linked answer is bad and I down voted it. The best way to deal with that answer should not be to "edit" it, but down vote it for all the bad information it contains. The person didn't know what they were talking about. It reads like cursory knowledge of the topic distorted into an authoritative answer.

I added my own answer which I think is better.

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/80999/23919